# How to join a chat room with specified number of messages

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

Currently I'm joining a chat room like this.

```
_xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_roomStorage
                                                           jid:roomJID
                                                 dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [_xmppRoom activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
    [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self
            delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSString *profileId = @"123456";

    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:profileId history:nil password:myPassword];
```

I want to retrieve only a specified number of messages as a chat history. Currently it is retrieving all the messages at once, which is causing problems with long chat history.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer I found. You've to send an XML element with max stanzas specified.

Here's the code.

```
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:roomID];
    _xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_roomStorage
                                                           jid:roomJID
                                                 dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [_xmppRoom activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
    [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self
            delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSString *profileId = @"123456";

    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
    [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"10"];
    [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:profileId history:history password:myPassword];
```